# PHP- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'readphp' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to get data from `mysql` using this template but it is not working and I am unable find errors in below code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection); // Selecting Database
//MySQL Query to read data
$query = mysql_query("select * from employee", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<b><a href="readphp.php?id={$row['employee_id']}">{$row['employee_name']}</a></b>";
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

I am getting below Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'readphp' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
```

Comment: Sorry Errors Indicating on this line
echo "<b><a href="readphp.php?id={$row['employee_id']}">{$row['employee_name']}</a></b>";

Comment: Further suggestion: Use mysqli_*-functions. mysql_*-functions are deprecated.

Comment: You are mixing PHP and HTML-Limiters ("). That's why it does not work. You Need to write the Syntax like echo '<a href="#">'; or echo "<a href='#'>";

Comment: Well you see php is giving you error on parts it should not interpret at all. You should find why is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `"` when inside other quotes `"`. Change :

`echo "<b><a href="readphp.php?id={$row['employee_id']}">{$row['employee_name']}</a></b>";`

To :

`echo "<b><a href=\"readphp.php?id={$row['employee_id']}\">{$row['employee_name']}</a></b>";`

Answer (score 0):

Change " to ' of href url. it conflicts with open comma.

```
echo "<b><a href='readphp.php?id={$row['employee_id']}'>{$row['employee_name']}</a></b>";


<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection); // Selecting Database
//MySQL Query to read data
$query = mysql_query("select * from employee", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<b><a href='readphp.php?id={$row['employee_id']}'>{$row['employee_name']}</a></b>";
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```